# Incompatible node.js version

Tags: node.js, npm

I used to install **node-png**: `npm install node-png  -g`

I got a message says:

> npm WARN engine node-png@0.4.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})

How to fix it, note: **I use earlier version** ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NVM to manage your node js versions and just use an old version on the project the you need that npm for.

here is a [link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I use windows and I installed the mvn and i got:
  ERROR open \settings.txt: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: In this page you can see an explanation for a solution: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

For Linux/Unix environment you can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) package. Although it works great nvm doesn't support windows, the existing alternatives are:

- [nvmw](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw)
- [nwm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Though this can end up in a Problem it usually does not matter, as long as you are not using an actively developed Module.

A solution is to use a NVM, Node version Manager